# [UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift

When I run the application and click the Yes button, The application will crash. But the No button working fine. Did anyone know what is the error?

Here is the error:

```
2019-03-12 23:05:53.139631+0000 surveyPF[81734:12033947] -[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe1c4416eb0
2019-03-12 23:05:53.148796+0000 surveyPF[81734:12033947] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe1c4416eb0'
```

And here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class FirstQViewController: UIViewController {
    var IDtext: String?
    var DateText: String?
    var answer: String?

    @IBAction func viewBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {

        switch sender.tag {
        case 0: answer = "Yes"
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "firstSegue", sender: self)
        case 1: answer = "No"
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondSegue", sender: self)
        default:
            print("Nothing")
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "firstSegue", let dest = segue.destination as? SecondQViewController {
            dest.IDtext = self.IDtext
            dest.DateText = self.DateText
            dest.answer = self.answer
        } else if segue.identifier == "secondSegue", let dest = segue.destination as? ThirdQViewController {
            dest.IDtext = self.IDtext
            dest.DateText = self.DateText
            dest.answer = self.answer
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click Yes, you segue to an instance of `SecondQViewController`. It seems that somewhere in that view controller you are setting the `text` property of some view that you expect to have a `text` property (such as a `UILabel`, `UITextField`, or `UITextView`) but your storyboard for that view controller has that view set as a `UIView` and not the more specific class type.

You need to check the views in the storyboard for the view controller and see which view is set as a plain old `UIView` instead of a more specific type of view that actually has a `text` property.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was like this (may be helpful for others as well)

1. We had an old Objective-C class, which subclassed the UITextField:

   ```
   @interface CustomTextField: UITextField
   ```
2. On the storyboard, someone set Custom Class `CustomTextField` **on UIView**. Somehow this was working fine for years.
3. But when we **migrated `CustomTextField` to Swift** (pretty much one-to-one, no major changes were done), the UIView, which had Custom Class set to `CustomTextField` started crashing with the same exception:

   > [UIView setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance ...

So the solution was to replace UIView on the storyboard with the actual `UITextField`